# Power BI - Cumulative SUM filtered by current row values

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, measure

I have a table with three columns - list_id, id, daily_return. id is basically a number sequence increment, reset for every list_id.

```
Example:
list_id id  daily_return
1       1   0.2
1       2   0.18
1       3   0.35
2       1   0.15
2       2   0.18
2       3   0.23
```

I need to create a calculated measure on the chart I am creating such that it creates a running total of daily_return for the same list_id, ordered by the id column.

I am creating a measure in the chart, since I want the rows to be filtered by the user and the calculation itself will be more complex.

**How do I get the current list_id and id, so I may use it in my formula?**

This is what I have so far. I tried using EARLIER/EARLIEST without success.

```
cumulative_return = CALCULATE(SUM('CMC Daily Return'[daily_return]), 'CMC Daily Return'[list_id]=EARLIER([list_id]), 'CMC Daily Return'[id]<=EARLIER([id]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following formula that works, but if there is a better one, then I am all ears.

```
cumulative_return = CALCULATE(SUM('CMC Daily Return'[daily_return]), FILTER( ALLSELECTED('CMC Daily Return'), 'CMC Daily Return'[list_id] = max('CMC Daily Return'[list_id]) ), FILTER( ALLSELECTED('CMC Daily Return'), 'CMC Daily Return'[id] <= max('CMC Daily Return'[id]) ) )
```